# How to play old online games with joystick?

Tags: gaming, peripherals

I have a Logitech USB joystick. When I try to play old games online (I'm particularly interested in Speedball and Speedball 2, but the problem appears in others, too), the keyboard works, but the joystick doesn't.

(https://archive.org/details/msdos_Speedball_1988)

(https://archive.org/details/msdos_Speedball_2_-_Brutal_Deluxe_1992)

It seems software-related or emulator-related. For example, if I use an online joystick tester(https://gamepad-tester.com/), it seems to work fine there.

I run on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: You likely need an older computer. That technology died quite a while back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't used a Joystick in years, but I recall remapping the buttons in the past for games. *(Can't recall what I used, I think it was the software that came with it.)* I'm not sure if this will help, but seeing how the games work with the keyboard you should be able to use something like this.

[UCR](https://github.com/Snoothy/UCR) (Universal Control Remapper)

The project is based on [Universal Joystick Remapper](https://github.com/evilC/AHK-Universal-Joystick-Remapper) and [AutoHotKeys Universal Control Remapper](https://github.com/evilC/UCR). It takes the input of the device and then converts the output to another device. In this case, it would take the Joystick input and export that out to keyboard output for the game.

If that doesn't work, you could look at other Joystick/controller remappers.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I was stuck for a time because, to send the output of the jouystick to the keyboard, you need to install a plugin called "Interception". But it was not difficult. "No te acostarás sin saber una cosa más".